# Are EAX , EBX registers 64 bit in length in modern processors

Tags: cpu, assembly

The EAX, EBX and ECX registers on a cpu are they 64 bits for a 64-bit cpu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they still refer to a 32bit register. But they are part of 64bit registries RAX, RBX and RCX.

The main reason for this is backward compatibility.